# Provision SharePoint Foundation Search with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

After a recent patching, it was discovered that the Search Service was not returning results to users.
On visiting the Search Service Application, at the top of the page:

ERROR:  "Crawl Status:  The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component.  Verify that the administration component 'GUID' in search application 'SearchServiceApplication' is in a good state and try again."

The admin noticed errors in the event logs and diagnostic logs, and made the determination to delete the search service application, and re-create it.
They were unable to re-create the Search Service Application.

Currently, the Manage Services on Server within Central Administration, SharePoint Foundation Search does not appear.  The Foundation SearchServiceInstance was unprovisioned, after it was noticed that the instances were all disabled and pointing to nonexistent databases.
There are currently no Foundation  SearchServiceInstances, and no search databases listed in Get-SPDatabase.

A new enterprise Search Service Application was created, and is currently crawling successfully, but search results are not rendered from within the application, and searches return a Search Web Part error.

Technet articles suggest that there may be a means of setting the SearchServiceInstance properties, but I'm not seeing a means of creating and provisioning the service.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620538(v=office.14).aspx

What is the safest way to create and provision a new foundation Search Service Instance (not the enterprise searchserviceinstance) on the farm with the least user impact?  I have a feeling that this may be the root cause.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server configuration/deployment tech support.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed (apologies for taking so long to comment).
The cause was multifold.
The farm admin had deleted the SearchServiceInstance (not the EnterpriseSearchServiceInstance) through PowerShell, rather than through Central Admin.  This caused any new Search Service applications to crawl and store results, but the Enterprise Search Service Site Collection was unable to render the web parts.

On reviewing the proxies, I discovered that there were proxies listed for search service applications which no longer existed.

I confirmed with a SharePoint buddy of mine at Microsoft (J. Robinson) that the PSCONFIG was the only way to get the Foundation Search Service resisted within Central Admin.

Once this was done, and the service was started on the server, I created a new Search Service Application through PowerShell, and removed the old proxy entries, setting the new Enterprise Search Service Application proxy to be the default.  Voila, Search web parts were able to render correctly, and one more issue resolved.